# How to remove cache automatically from a custom module

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm building a custom module like described here (https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules) for drupal 8. That's mostly dynamic content that changes with some WebServices calls. My problem is that the internal drupal 8 cache is automatically caching everything, including token and javascripts.

So question is :
- can I define somewhere in the module, don't cache it?

Thanks

Comment: My idea: Drupal won't cache it if he's not aware of it. So if you include your JS directly from your html template it shouldn't be cached by Drupal. But I'm also interested in better solution.

Comment: kind of dirty workaround, but that's pretty smart and working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're dealing with render array caching, but if so you could try:

```
$build['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
```

You can read more about it in [Cacheability of render arrays](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/cacheability-of-render-arrays).